# How to access local methods inside a class in module of nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, es6-modules, es6-class

I have a module having a class

```
"use strict";

module.exports = class Execute {

    constructor(){

        }


    run(success) 
    {
       prepare( function(){
            execute(success);
        });
    }


    prepare(success)
    {
        }
```

what i want is to access the prepare function from the run function, but both are in same class.so how can i do this?

Comment: I strongly suggest moving to Promises instead of callbacks.

Comment: can i do this
`"use strict";

module.exports = class Execute_code {

    constructor(){
}

 run(success) 
    {
        
       this.prepare( function(){
            this.execute(success);
        });
    }


    prepare(success)
    {
}

execute(){
}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the method on the instance of the object.

```
this.prepare()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `this` to access local method in a class.

```
    "use strict";

module.exports = class Execute {

    constructor(){

        }


    run(success) 
    {
       this.prepare( () => {
            execute(success);
        });
    }


    prepare(success)
    {
        }
}
```